# Overriding computed property with stored one

Tags: swift, properties

Suppose I have a classes A and B like this:

```
class A {
    var x: Int { return 9 }
    func p() {  print(x) }
}

class B: A {
    ...
}

let v: A = B()
v.p()
```

And then I override x in B in three different ways:

```
class B: A {

    // OPTION 1: FINE - prints 10
    override var x: Int { return 10 }

    // OPTION 2: ERROR - cannot override with a stored property 'x'
    override var x = 10

    // OPTION 3: FINE - prints 10
    override lazy var x = 10

}
```

Can someone explain me what's wrong in overriding a computed property with a stored property, and why is everything suddenly fixed when I declare it lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real technical reason why you cannot override a property with a stored property; it has getters and setters (accessors), which can override the accessors of the property to override. It should just be equivalent to overriding with a computed property that then forwards onto a stored property.

However I do foresee one slight complication with allowing this: property observer overrides.

Consider the following example:

```
class C {
  var f: Int {
    get { return 5 }
    set { print("C says f was set") }
  }
}

class D : C {
  override var f: Int {
    didSet {
      print("D says f was set")
    }
  }
}

let d = D()
print(d.f)
d.f = 7
print(d.f)

// 5
// C says f was set
// D says f was set
// 5
```

We can override `f`'s `didSet` in `D`. In this case, `override var f: Int` is essentially treated as a computed property with a getter and setter that forwards onto `super`, with an additional call onto the `didSet` implementation in the setter.

No actual *storage* is introduced by `D` here. So why is this problematic? Well, how would we tell the compiler that we *do* actually want storage for `f`? Adding an initialiser expression (`= 10`) could communicate that, but not all stored properties have default values; most are initialised from the class' designated initialiser. We'd probably need an attribute of some kind, but for such a limited use case, it doesn't seem like a particularly useful change to the language.

The `lazy` case is clear-cut because we cannot add property observers to them.

Although that all being said, the particular case you present should *also* be clear cut; as the base property only has a getter, so there's no property observers to override. I would recommend you [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/) to (hopefully) see what the Swift team have to say about this.

You can always achieve the same result with a computed property override that then forwards onto a stored property though:

```
class C {
  var f: Int {
    return 9
  }
}

class D : C {

  private var _f: Int = 10

  override var f: Int {
    get { return _f }
    set { _f  = newValue }
  }
}

let d = D()
print(d.f) // 10
d.f = 7
print(d.f) // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t override read-only computed property with writeable stored property.

> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but can’t be set to a different value.

[Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Read-Only-Computed-Properties)