# Cannot override with a stored property in Swift

Tags: swift, overriding

What is the right way to override lazy var in Swift 4.1?
The following code work fine in swift 4.0 but since swift 4.1 I have warning on override, so I guess it'll be unavailable in swift 5

I used to:

```
class A {

    lazy var myVar: String = {
        return "A"
    }()
}

class B: A {

    override lazy var myVar: String = { // WARNING Cannot override with a stored property myVar
        return "B"
    }()
}
```

I guess this is something like this but its not sexy..

```
class A {

    lazy var myVar: String = {
        return createMyVar()
    }()

    func createMyVar() -> String {
        return "A"
    }
}

class B: A {

    override func createMyVar() -> String {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine, under `Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9`

Comment: @Alexander The question is asking about Swift 4.1. It works in 4.0 but apparently not 4.1 (I don't have Xcode 9.3 yet so I can't check).

Comment: "It works in 4.0 but apparently not 4.1" That's something the question should mention. I was under the impression that the diff would be between major Swift version like 2 or 3 and 4, not between minor versions 4.0 and 4.1

Comment: ? This error has been around since Swift 3.

Comment: Lazy property are used at run time when you have to use it for some costly operations, so you can not override Lazy property in your child class

Comment: @ShauketSheikh well it's working on swift 4 but have a warning in 4.1

Comment: @ArnaudDorgans I have this exact same problem. And I Would REALLY like to use subclassing. Please let me know if you come up with some elegant solution. Hamish solution might be what we need to do, but I rather not introduce those extra lines of code...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Although there's no technical reason why you cannot override a property with one that introduces storage (although it can raise ambiguities with observer overrides; see [this Q&A for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46676992/2976878)), Swift doesn't currently allow you to do so.

The fact that in 4.0 you could override a property with a `lazy` property [was unintended](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6165) (as the override introduces storage), and so you'll get a warning in 4.1 and an error in Swift 5 mode in order to preserve source compatibility (implemented in [#13304](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13304)).

You can however achieve the same result with a forwarding computed property though:

```
class A {
  lazy var myVar: String = "A"
}

class B : A {

  // Note that this isn't a particulary compelling case for using 'lazy', as
  // the initialiser expression is not expensive.
  private lazy var _myVar: String = "B"

  override var myVar: String {
    get { return _myVar }
    set { _myVar = newValue }
  }
}
```